# Command Prompt / Anaconda Command Prompt not opening in Windows 11

Tags: python, windows, powershell, command-line, anaconda

I am doing a research project that involves me running terminals in the Anaconda Command Prompt. I was able to install and work the current version of Anaconda (4.12) and get the command prompt running there, but I had to depreciate my version of Anaconda to 4.2 so I can work on my project using Python 3.5. That version of Anaconda could not open the Anaconda Command Prompt or the Anaconda Navigator on my machine, so I tried reinstalling the current version of Anaconda after uninstalling 4.2; however, now I have the problem where the Anaconda Command Prompt can't open (but I've been able to run Anaconda Navigator). I tried doing the following things to see if I could fix this issue:

1. Opening the Anaconda Command Prompt through the Windows Command Prompt; however, now I have the added problem of the Windows Command Prompt not opening (which I tried fixing in the steps below)
2. Running the command prompt in Windows Safe Boot Mode. This method did open the command prompt, but it opened it up under the wrong letter drive. On this mode, I get the directory:
   X:\windows\system32
   What confuses me is that I don't even have an X: drive on my machine.
3. Trying to use some of the commands I was going to use in the command prompt in Powershell; however, when I opened powershell, I got an error message regarding Execution Policies. I was able to get the error fixed by changing some of the Execution Policies. I changed the execution policy on CurrentUser and LocalMachine to Unrestricted. This solved the problem on Powershell, but didn't fix the problem with opening the command prompt.
4. Going back into the Safe Boot Mode Command Prompt and seeing if the letter drive had been fixed to the default C:. The letter drive is still X:.

I don't know what to do to fix this problem. I've tried many of the things I read online from windows and other forums, but so far they haven't worked.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, here is the solution (extracted from Microsoft Assistance Service):

The fix was to open Registry Editor by searching "regedit" in the start menu, then search for "autorun" in the Edit tab, and delete the "autorun" file from the system through right click.

The offending "autorun" element is located under the key:
`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor`
and contains an errorneous value `if exists` which prevented `cmd.exe` from starting properly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: OMG Thank you so much!! I literally spend 2 hours on the internet for this stupid bug

Comment: This actually works! After leaving the value of AutoRun blank, the command prompt now starts properly.

Comment: What a amazing solution! I've uninstalled anaconda and deleted a folder name `.anaconda` in `AppData`, then I cannot open cmd anymore. This is probably a anaconda installer behaviour!